# creating different different database on each submission of creat_account

Tags: mysql, database, authentication

Here my requirement is little bit complicated but I have to finish this task anyhow please help

I am using create_account page for registration purpose and in this form i will add one column like "company name", remaining everything will be same in form and when I will submit form, at this moment separate database has to be created with particular company name and table will be created in particular database and all details will be stored in to that table. 
and now Again if i submit this form with another company name ,at the same time another database has to be created.
it will continue and multiple databases will be created for each submission of form (for different different company ).

I want new database because once I will login then I will be having option in navigation bar like (adding employee name, adding department, deleting employee name etc... ) so for this purpose i will be using new database and. And this database will be for particular company.Likewise so many instance database has to be created

Does anyone know or having idea about it please reply, it will be appreciable

Comment: What are you using as a front end (php?)

Comment: you don't need a new database for this, just a new entry in the "companies" table, surely? Otherwise you're just creating huge amounts of duplication.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for Reply, I am using HTML as front End

Comment: @ADyson I want new database because once I will login then I will be having option in navigation bar like (adding employee name, adding department, deleting employee name etc... ) so for this purpose i will be using new database and. And this database will be for particular company.Likewise so many instance database has to be created. Any leads how to do the same?????

Comment: @Yuvrajverma You can do that with a single database also. You should check this http://labs.octivi.com/database-design-in-saas-platforms/. While doing this DB structure you should consider few points like scalability, maintainability, code management. Your way may put you in a lot of trouble in future.

Comment: @Yuvrajverma there's no reason you need a separate database for any of that. Your app just works out who is logged in, retrieves the appropriate info from a table for that login ID and displays that info including site name etc. But per-customer DBs adds a level of indirection where you have to lookup login ID in master DB, then login to 2nd DB to get the real data. Doesn't add much (if any) security really, makes you do extra queries/connections, and also causes a maintenance headache when you want to upgrade the system and have to apply the same changes to hundreds of identical DB instances.

Comment: @Yuvrajverma if you're doing SaaS and you actually want a separate instance for each customer then you should consider creating a whole virtual environment in the cloud for each, with its own network, domain name, DB servers, app servers and the rest. You can make it automated with templates in most cloud hosts. Then you genuinely have separation for each customer and enhanced security. And you can be more flexible about upgrades, doing each customer separately or all at once, as you/they choose.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a new database from your code with any language but the point is **whether that a feasible solution? Will you be able to scale it to 5k DB's?**

Sounds like you are building a SaaS application. If you are yet to finalize your DB structure then I'll highly recommend doing some more research.
Go through articles like

- http://labs.octivi.com/database-design-in-saas-platforms/
- http://support.techcello.com/support/solutions/articles/4000012867-how-to-pick-a-right-data-isolation-model-for-my-saas-application-

**Just to answer your question** you can easily crease DB from, can't show example here because you haven't mentioned which language you are looking for.

**Updated**
For PHP you can use something like this:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password');
if (!$connection) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Make client_db the current database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('client_db', $connection);

if (!$db_selected) {
  // If not then create
  $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE client_db';

  if (mysql_query($sql, $connection)) {
      echo "Database client_db created successfully\n";
  } else {
      echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
  }
}

mysql_close($connection)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using HTML and bootstrap at front end and PHP at Back end. Currently I am running my website on XAMPP localhost server.

Comment: @RameshMhetre the `mysql_` API you've shown here has been deprecated for a long time, and removed entirely in PHP7. It has security issues, not the least of which is the inability to use parameterised queries and prepared statements to protect against SQL injection attacks. It's quite bad advice to suggest creating new code using this library. Developers should be working to remove this from their legacy code, not create new solutions with it. Consider revising to use `mysqli` or `PDO`.  I agree with your overall sentiment though that this is not likely to be a scalable design.

Comment: Agreed! My idea was to just show him a path & possibilities. In fact, if he is using any framework then he has to go with code standards of his framework.